# MVC vs N-tier architecture - Singletons vs Objects (Django/Python)

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller, architecture, n-tier-architecture

I have a class in Django that is responsible for speaking to another service via http.  Currently in the application it is being used as a Singleton.  However, each method requires the same 2-3 pieces of data (from the user's session) to run. In addition, each method has to make several calls to other methods in the class, meaning the data gets passed as arguments very frequently

```
class MySingletonClass():
    def get_user_group(self, email, token):
        # request to service

    def get_user_picture(self, email, token, pic_id):
        # request to service

    def get_user_item(self, email, token, item_id):
        # request to service
```

There are about 14 methods in all and they are contacted through a simple Api layer in Django.  Rather than passing the `email` and `token` every time, I could simply pass the `session` itself. but then I would have to either set up scoped vars or type a lot more characters

```
def get_user_group(self, session):
    email = session.get("email")
    token = session.get("token")
```

This seems repetitive.  My solution was to stop using a Singleton and instantiate the class with the session info at the API-layer

```
def my_api_endpoint(request):
    myObj = MyClass(request.session)

    return HttpResponse(myObj.get_user_group())



class MyClass():
        def __init__(self, session):
            self.email = session.get("email")
            self.token = session.get("token")

        def get_user_group(self):
            # request to service

        def get_user_picture(self, pic_id):
            # request to service

        def get_user_item(self, item_id):
            # request to service
```

However, my co-worker said that the Singleton pattern is much better because it adheres better to N-tier architecture.  I hadn't heard the term before, but even after reading all the `MVC v n-tier` questions on StackOverflow, I still don't seem to get where he's coming from.  As best I can tell n-tier just means everything communicates through an intermediary layer rather than talking to components directly.  I don't see how my not using singletons has made my program worse or less idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

MVC and n-tier architecture are as the name of the last implies ARCHITECTURAL patterns (not even mutualy exclusive).

Singleton is a DESIGN pattern.

In an application with a certain architecture you can use any number of design patterns, according to the application's use cases. This use cases make one or more design patterns optimal for implementing them.

In case of the Singleton, if you think there should be only one instance of that class in your application then you use it, if multiple instances are needed or more suitable, you don't. This is the only criteria.

So no, you did not do nothing wrong,